# get_application_id() behaviour with aliased app id

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was forced to alias my app name after migrating to the High Replication Datastore.

I use the google.appengine.api.app_identity.get_application_id() method throughout my app, but now it returns the new app id instead of the original one even when visiting via the old app id url.

Is there a way to output the original app id?

thanks

Comment: Could you explain more? How did you go about aliasing your app name?

Comment: aliasing is an option in the migration process from Master Slave to High Replication Datastore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - `get_application_id` returns the ID of the app that is actually serving your request. You can examine the hostname to see if the request was directed to `oldappid.appspot.com`.

Comment: thanks Nick, i guess I'll have to use hostname and strip out "appspot.com"